# data.table backward rolling join between integer and numeric columns

Tags: r, join, data.table

Came across an unexpected behavior today involving data.table's rolling join.  I want to do a rolling join between an integer type column and a numeric type column.  The forward roll works as I expected but the backwards roll doesn't.

```
dt1<-data.table(x=as.integer(c(1,2)))
dt2<-data.table(x=c(1.5))

setkey(dt1, "x")
setkey(dt2, "x")

dt1[dt2, roll=TRUE] #Expected behavior
   x
1: 1

dt1[dt2, roll=-Inf] #Unexpected behavior
   x
1: 1
```

Is this a bug or is this behavior documented?  Just guessing but it looks like data.table is casting the numeric column to an integer internally instead of casting the integer column to numeric.

Comment: It might be helpful if you include some other values, columns to see what's going on. How about `dt1<-data.table(x=as.integer(c(1,2,5,8)), y=letters[1:4]);dt2<-data.table(x=c(1.5, 3.2, 7.5), z=letters[23:25])`? It seems just the first join is unexpected? And to be clear, your expectation is no join at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior, albeit with a buried warning. What happens is that `dt2$x` is coerced to an integer, so neither of your rolls is doing anything and it's a straight up merge with the value of 1.

To see the warning use `verbose=TRUE`:

```
dt1[dt2, verbose = TRUE]
#Coercing 'double' column i.'x' to 'integer' to match type of x.'x'. Please avoid coercion for efficiency.
#Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
#   x
#1: 1
```

Comment: btw imo the warning should not be silent like this